# in SQL is there a code to fill in a new column when you add a new column to a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I find it difficult to fill a new column that I just added to an already existing table in SQL

I tried the Insert command, to fill in the table afresh, but couldn't see it true because the table has 1445 rows

Comment: Other than the `DEFAULT` option when adding the new column, there's nothing that will automatically fill it in. You need to use an `UPDATE` query to update existing rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify a default value when you add the column:

```sql
ALTER TALE mytable ADD COLUMN new_column VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'my_value'
```

Alternatively, once you added the column, you could use an `update` statement:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET    new_column = 'my_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the answer above you can use ALTER TABLE to add a new column

```
 ALTER TABLE dummy
 ADD temp_column VARCHAR(50);
```

Then you can use the update and add a where statement to be more specific

```
 UPDATE dummy
-> SET temp_column = 'DEFAULT'
-> where id > 10;
```

**Alternatively** you could try using [Five](https://five.co/), you can import your database in it as an SQL dump, it actually allows you to do way more with new columns, like copy data from an existing field in the table or fill in the values from a query

[here is an image of Five prompting you to fill in values for a new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkJpN.png)

there are other things as well like you can write queries directly in Five, reuse the queries and the tables can be generated with simple point and click.

Disclaimer: I work for Five